# How to set Tomcat.runtime.environment.version as PROD on the web server?

Tags: variables, tomcat

I want to set Tomcat environment variable as PROD. I tried by putting

```
set "ENVIRONMENT=PROD"
set JAVA_OPTS="-Dtomcat.runtime.environment.version=PROD"
```

in `catalina.bat`
and tried to retrieve it with

```
env = System.getProperty("tomcat.runtime.environment.version");
```

but every time `env` is null! Where exactly does the variable have to be declared in `catalina.bat` and what's the perfect syntax to set the environment variable? Other possible ways to declare variables are also welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are on Windows and in *production*, I'm going to assume that you are using a Microsoft Windows Service for Tomcat. If that's the case, the .bat files are completely ignored when launching and stopping Tomcat. There is a service binary that reads the configuration from the Windows Registry and no disk-based scripts are used at all.

If you run the program called [`tomcatXw.exe`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html) (where `X` is your Tomcat major version number), that will run the configuration GUI. From there, you can configure everything stored in the Registry.

Go to the "System Properties" tab and add your system property `-Dtomcat.runtime.environment.version=PROD` to the list of properties already found in there. Restart your service and you should be able to see the new system property available to your application (actually the whole JVM, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your response Christopher, I tried to declare a environment variable in startup.bat/Catalina.bat and am trying to call the same using System.getProperty("propertyName") but it's returning a null value. I've tried the same by creating a new file setenv.bat and which "System Properties" tab are you exactly referring to? Where can I find that?

Comment: Environment variables are different than system properties. You need to launch Java with `-Dpropname=value` in order to use `System.getProperty("propertyName")`. Environment variables are fetched with `System.getenv(String name)`. You really shouldn't use environment variables with Java.

Comment: Are you using a Windows Service or not? If so, stop editing `bin/*.bat` because they are ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, it's true that it's neglecting bat files. The issue is resolved when I declared variables in catalina.properties.

Comment: It would still be better to defined your system properties in the "System Properties" tab in `tomcatXw.exe`'s configuration screen. I'm not sure why you are resisting that so much.

Comment: `tomcatXw.exe` is not a Windows Service. It's a regular program. You can run it from the CLI or from Start | Run.... You can find the binary in Tomcat's installation directory under `bin/`.